# Freezing specific values in a weight matrix in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Assuming I have a a weight matrix that looks like `[[a , b ], [c, d]]`, is it possible in Tensorflow to fix the values of `b` and `c` to zero such that they don't change during optimization?

Comment: So you want a Tensor with some values being variables and trainables and other values being constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sample code:

```
A = tf.Variable([[1., 0.], [3., 0.]])
A1 = A[:,0:1] # just some slicing of your variable
A2 = A[:,1:2]
A2_stop = tf.stop_gradient(tf.identity(A2)) 
A = tf.concat((A1, A2_stop), axis=1)
```

Actually, `tf.identity` is needed to stop the gradient before A2.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this, you can

1. Break apart your weight matrix into multiple variables, and make only some of them trainable.
2. Hack the gradient calculation to be zero for the constant elements.
3. Hack the gradient application to reset the values of the constant elements.